# How do you import custom classes into Django views.py?

Tags: python, django, module, importerror

I'm trying to import a group of python classes from my mdt folder into `views.py`, but every time I try and run the view with the localhost, I get a ModuleNotFoundError for the Network class. I also know my FoliumMap class is not importing properly as when I remove the part of the code that returns the error for the Network class, I can't access a function from the FoliumMap class. I've seen some questions about this, and tried to do what they've said, but I still either get the same ModuleNotFoundError, or it can't find the file at all. I'm just really struggling to see what I'm missing.

Other than what I have below, I haven't changed any of the Django generated files except to get the urls & localhost working.

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbmCN.png) the file structure at the moment, where I'm trying to import the `FoliumMap` class in `FoliumMap.py` file, and the `Network`, `Segment` and `Node` classes from the `Network.py` file.

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcx0K.png) the error page that I keep getting.

This is all the code in `views.py`:

```
from .mdt.FoliumMap import *
from .mdt.Network import *
import pickle
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def show_emissions(request):  
    fol = FoliumMap()
    network = pickle.load( open( "*obj filepath*", "rb" ) )
    fol.draw_network(network, metric='emissions')
    fol.add_layers()
    folium.LayerControl(collapsed=False).add_to(fol.map)
    m=fol.get_map()._repr_html_()
    context = {'my_map': m}
    return render(request, 'mdt_webapp/index.html', context)
```

Here's most of my `settings.py` (I haven't really changed the rest from the django generated version):

```
...
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'mdt_webapp',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
...
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `__init__.py` file inside **mdt** folder. now try

Explanation:
When you create `__init__.py` file python consider mdt as a module, and you can import any file inside that module

Comment: No, sorry I still seem to get the same error

Comment: can you provide the screenshots that show the updated code and error?

Comment: I can, but it's still just the same error as before

Comment: just share the new folder structure and error

Comment: here's the file structure: https://imgur.com/a/nimRzcp, and here's the error page: https://imgur.com/a/YWwM15N

Answer (score 0):

here the mdt directory is inside your mdt_webapp directory. And you are trying to import the classes which are located inside the mdt directory. Just remove the . from your import or you can use full path.

```
from mdt_webapp.mdt.FoliumMap import *
```

But never do a blind import in python it is not recommended. So import your classes like this.

```
from mdt_webapp.mdt.FoliumMap import FoliumMap
from mdt_webapp.mdt.Network import Network, Segment, Node
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I still get exactly the same error as before

Comment: Hi, can you say me one thing that is the mdt_webapp directory inside the mdt_project directory? And can you paste here the settings.BASE_DIR value?

Comment: @littlechef please try this and let me know your results. from mdt_project.mdt_webapp.mdt.FoliumMap import FoliumMap

Comment: Sorry for not responding quickly, I've been very busy the past few days, but thank you so much for helping me. I still get the same `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Network'` error as in my original screenshot when using `from mdt_webapp.mdt.FoliumMap import FoliumMap`, and my settings.BASE_DIR value is still the default `BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent`.

Comment: You’re welcome. But please try “from mdt_project.mdt_webapp.mdt.FoliumMap import FoliumMap” and let me know if it works

Comment: When I try `from mdt_project.mdt_webapp.mdt.FoliumMap import FoliumMap`, it throws a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mdt_project.mdt_webapp'` error. I think the thing is, if I use `from mdt_webapp.mdt.FoliumMap import FoliumMap`, django is able to find the file, as I can still run the server with no errors (just not using the imported files). So, maybe it's something to do with my settings file and what modules it can actually read, opposed to the file path? I'm not sure, but I'm just wondering if there's something I should have added to the settings file.